# Change z index in a framer motion animation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I'm making a dropdown menu and I wanted to create an animation using framer motion. The problem I encounered is that when the animation starts the component hides under the other components on the website until the animation ends. I have seen that you can specify zIndex property but it doesn't seem to work. Did anyone have a similar problem? Any solution?

Comment: Share code/part of the code, and if you have overflow effect it means u have problem with css.

Comment: You're right I changed z index of other components and now it works fine, thanks